# Receiving an Error when Trying to Delete a File?

Tags: command-line, uninstall, rm

I'm trying to remove some files from an installation I screwed up. I went to the directory in the terminal, and typed `sudo rm PCSX` but it tells me it doesn't exist even though I can quite clearly see it. How do I fix this?

Comment: I can't `ls -a` because there is too much in the directory and it gets cut off.

Comment: If it is a directory you will want to use `sudo rm -r PCSX` and terminal is case sensitive. **BE VERY CAREFUL WHEN USING `sudo rm -r`** Also as @Oli suggested could be the wrong directory. Although if you are trying to remove the install then maybe try `dpkg -r pcsxr`

Comment: `dpkg -r pcsxr` doesn't work as I never fully installed it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `sudo rm PCSX` tells you something doesn't exist, it probably doesn't exist in your current working directory. That means you're either...

- Telling it the wrong filename. You can use `ls -al | less` to browse the cwd.
- Or you're in the wrong directory and you should `cd` into the correct one.

Comment: I apologize for the sloppiness, I don't have GIMP on my machine. [link](http://i.imgur.com/qbK0QBO.png?1) This is the directory with the file. [link](http://i.imgur.com/PDXuNR7.png?1) This is the terminal. As you can see, I am in the same directory, and it tells me the file doesn't exist.

Comment: @kookman98 Yeah I don't have any files like the nautilus display in `/usr/share/app-install/desktop/`. It might be interpreting the launchers? Get the proper name with: `ls -a /usr/share/app-install/desktop/ | less`

Comment: it says pcsxr:pcsx.desktop

Comment: And there's your filename. `sudo rm /usr/share/app-install/desktop/pcsxr:pcsx.desktop`

Comment: Well that seemed just a tad complicated, but it worked, thanks!